# Unhandled Promise Rejection: NotAllowedError: The request is not allowed by the user agent

Tags: typescript, safari, audiocontext

I am trying to play audio on safari on the Iphone X when the user gives his first input, but I keep getting the error

```
Unhandled Promise Rejection: NotAllowedError: The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, posible because the user denied permission
```

When I try to play the background sound I get the error after the following line.

```
this.getAudio("assets/sounds/soundtrack.mp3").tryPlay();
```

I even made my own sound class so I can prevent sound from being played untill permission is granted. This works great for sound effects. But it doesn't work for the background sound. How can I play the background sound after the first user input?

```
import App from "../../../app";
import * as createjs from "createjs-module";

export default class AudioManager {
  private map: Map<string, Sound>;

  private pointerDownHandler: () => void;

  constructor(sounds:Map<string, HTMLAudioElement>) {
    this.map = new Map<string, Sound>();

    sounds.forEach((value, key) => {
      this.map.set(key, new Sound(key, value));
      value.pause();
    });

    this.pointerDownHandler = this.requestAudioPermission;
    window.addEventListener("pointerdown", this.pointerDownHandler);
  }

  requestAudioPermission = async () => {
    const AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
    const ctx = new AudioContext();
    await ctx.resume();

    this.map.forEach((value) => {
      value.givePermissionToPlay();
    });

    this.getAudio("assets/sounds/soundtrack.mp3").tryPlay();
    window.removeEventListener("pointerdown", this.pointerDownHandler);
  };

  getAudio(key: string): Sound {
    return this.map.get(key) as Sound;
  }

  fadeMusic(sound: Sound, to: number) {
    sound.fade(to);
  }

  mute() {
    this.map.forEach((map) => {
      map.setMuted(true);
    });
  }

  unmute() {
    this.map.forEach((map) => {
      map.setMuted(false);
    });
  }
}

export class Sound {
  private name: string;
  private audioElement: HTMLAudioElement;
  private hasPermissionToPlay = false;

  public get muted(): boolean {
    return this.audioElement.muted;
  }

  constructor(name: string, audioElement: HTMLAudioElement) {
    this.name = name;
    this.audioElement = audioElement;
  }

  tryPlay() {
    if (this.hasPermissionToPlay) {
      this.audioElement.play();
      console.log(this.name);
    }
  }

  pause() {
    this.audioElement.pause();
  }

  setMuted(mute: boolean) {
    this.audioElement.muted = mute;
  }

  setVolume(volume: number) {
    this.audioElement.volume = volume;
  }

  setCurrentTime(time: number) {
    this.audioElement.currentTime = time;
  }

  setLoop(loop: boolean) {
    this.audioElement.loop = loop;
  }

  fade(to: number) {
    createjs.Tween.get(this.audioElement).to({ volume: to }, 500);
  }

  givePermissionToPlay() {
    this.hasPermissionToPlay = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Any fixes for this yet?

Comment: I ended up using the Howler package https://www.npmjs.com/package/howler sadly no fix